# Loop over list using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, loops

I was just wondering if you could help me please. I have the below code:

```
<li class="active">
    <div class="holder">
          <img src="#" data-name="test1">
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="holder">
          <img src="#" data-name="test1">
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="holder">
          <img src="#" data-name="test2">
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="holder">
          <img src="#" data-name="test1">
    </div>
</li>
```

I would like a method of looking at the current list item and the to look at the next one and then the next one until it finds the img with the name  **Test 2**. I have managed to get the current element. And I have found out how I can get the next element. But not the next element dependant on its children.

Could anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Hey all thanks for all of your answers. There is only one problem at the moment and I should of probably said before. See the code below:

```
<li class="active">
    <div class="holder">
      <img src="#" data-name="test2">
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="holder">
      <img src="#" data-name="test2">
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="holder">
      <img src="#" data-name="test2">
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="holder">
      <img src="#" data-name="test2">
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="holder">
      <img src="#" data-name="test1">
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="holder">
      <img src="#" data-name="test2">
    </div>
</li>
```

There could be many images named test2 but I only want to get the next image after the currently active image. For example it would skip the image test1

Comment: can you post the excepted result ?

Comment: Sure I would like to add the class "active" to the li of the image that has the name test 2

Comment: so you want to get the next element only if it has the image with data-name=test2?

Comment: Yes that is correct :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('img[data-name="test2"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
```

With jQuery, you'll often find little need for manually writing `for` loops in cases like these, when their selectors allow you to traverse the DOM a lot easier already.

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't mind downvotes at all, I like learning where I've went wrong, but I can only do that if there's an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$("li img[data-name=test2]").closest("li").addClass("active");
```

This will set the class directly to the element without looping them.

See [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pwtmyajw/)

Comment: My first answer set the class to the image. This one selects the li containing the img.

Answer (score 0):

Say you were currently on the second LI (which would be $("li:nth-child(1)") for the sake of the code below). To find the next sibling LI tags containing the image you want and add an active class would be something like below (haven't tested it):

```
$("li:nth-child(1)").nextAll("li img[data-name]='test2']").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score -2):

Based off of Alwad's answer and your follow up question:

```
$("li img[data-name]='test2']").closest("li").addClass("active");
```

edit:  scratch mine, mark Alwad's as correct, he edited his answer.
edit2:  stop editing your post/comments, folks end up marking me downwards. :(   I'm done editing this answer to chase your question edits. :)

Comment: You're adding a class to the `img`, he wants it on the `li`.

Comment: He's constantly editing his posts.  :-/     That's not what it said originally. :)

Comment: @DeeMac -- it's considered bad form to downvote someone else's answer that's the same as yours, in favor of your own.  Pretty tacky.    I'm looking at Barry's post that you downvoted.

Comment: I haven't downvoted a single answer. What exactly are you talking about? I didn't even downvote yours - and your answer was completely wrong.

Comment: Both mine and Barry's were downvoted in a question that the only other person here is you.   His was first, and correct, and nailed down to -1 last I saw.    Mine was downvoted (correctly, as it wasn't in sync with OPs edits) right after your comment.   If it wasn't you - it was some mysterious fan of yours following you around protecting your posts. :)

Comment: `Both mine and Barry's were downvoted in a question that the only other person here is you.` Downvotes on SO posts aren't restricted to only those participating at all. This question has been viewed "36 times". Could've been anyone.

Comment: By the way, your question is *still* wrong, and I *still* haven't downvoted. Why are you calling `.parent()`? The parent is a div, which he doesn't want to add a class to. Your two lines of code do entirely different things. Sort your answer out, it's useless.